# How to sort data by ascending order in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, collections, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using order by child to spisplay data into listView and the data is displayed by descending order, How can I set the order to ascending order in Android client Side?

```
ref.orderByChild("date_creation").limitToFirst(10).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

//date_creation is the date when user add Book "dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss" 
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Book valueBook = dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);
                        String titreLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getNom_livre();
                        String descLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getDesc_livre();
                        String prixLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getPrix_livre();
                        String timeToDisplay = valueBook.getDate_creation();
                        String filePathToDiplay = valueBook.getChemin_image();
                        String villeToDisplay = valueBook.getVille_livre();
                        String typeAnnToDisplat = valueBook.getType_annonce_selected();

                        item = new Book();

                        item.setNom_livre(titreLivreToDisplay);
                        item.setDesc_livre(descLivreToDisplay);
                        item.setPrix_livre(prixLivreToDisplay);
                        item.setDate_creation(timeToDisplay);
                        item.setChemin_image(filePathToDiplay);
                        item.setVille_livre(villeToDisplay);
                        item.setType_annonce_selected(typeAnnToDisplat);


                        feedItems.add(item);


                    }


                    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(AccueilActivity.this, feedItems);

                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
```

I want use Arraylist collections to sort data that I get From Database.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Book valueBook = dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);

                        String titreLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getNom_livre();
                        String descLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getDesc_livre();
                        String prixLivreToDisplay = valueBook.getPrix_livre();
                        String timeToDisplay = valueBook.getDate_creation();
                        String filePathToDiplay = valueBook.getChemin_image();
                        String villeToDisplay = valueBook.getVille_livre();
                        String typeAnnToDisplat = valueBook.getType_annonce_selected();

                        list.add(titreLivreToDisplay);
                        list.add( descLivreToDisplay);
                        list.add(prixLivreToDisplay);
                        list.add(timeToDisplay);
                        list.add(filePathToDiplay);
                        list.add( villeToDisplay);
                        list.add(typeAnnToDisplat);
Collections.sort(list);
```

I don't know how to implement that. How can I use this collections? How to use list to feed feedItems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you explained, you only want to reverse the order of your list. 
This can be easily done using a comparator.

```
// Defining the comparator
Comparator compare = Collections.reverseOrder();

// Sorting the list taking into account the comparator
Collections.sort(list, compare);
```

This code should reverse order your list.
Hope I have helped, otherwise, provide more information about the reverse order stage.

Comment: My  feedItems  is a list of book `List<Book> feedItems = new ArrayList<Book>();`  my other list is a list of string `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` How to use list to feed feedItems  ?

Comment: @Amal You can simply instantiate a new constructor of the Book class `item = new Book();`, add the items from `list` into your constructor. Finally, add that item into your `feedItems` ArrayList `feedItems.add(item);`. 
If it is not as you expected, please provide me more information of your problem.

Comment: I have this error : `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mydreambook.model.Book cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Collections.java:192)` at  `Collections.sort(feedItems,compare);`

Comment: I had to add `implements Comparable<Book> `in my Class Model

Comment: @Amal Glad that you have solved the problem. If you need any other help, just reply here.

Answer (score 0):

I want sorted data by ascending order , the solution was just use collections to reverse order that I had:

```
Collections.reverse(feedItems);
```